# Windows Powershell Reading Tab Delimited File Problem

Tags: powershell, csv

OK so what I'm trying to accomplish should in theory be very easy but I can't figure out what's going wrong. I am trying to use the import-csv cmdlet to read in a .tsv file.

My syntax is:

```
import-csv -path "myfile" -delimiter "`t"
```

The problem is that this only displays the first column from my file. Why are the other data columns not being displayed? I checked the file in notepad to verify that the data is in fact separated by a tab and it is.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure all the columns are tab separated?  [char[]](gc myfile -totalcount 1) |% {[int]$_}

Comment: yes the columns are absolutely tab separated because I am viewing the file in a text editor

Comment: Try this: (gc myfile -totalcount 1) -split "`t" Do you get each field on a separate line?

Comment: mjolinor, yes to your last question. That command displayed the first row from my file split up at the tabs on separate lines.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm out of ideas without seeing the actual data.

Comment: Worked for me with my sample tab seperated test csv file. +1 for seeing you data before providing an accurate answer

Comment: OK here's an example. For example if the text file contains this:

Column 1{tab}Column 2{tab}Column 3{tab}Column 4{end of line}
data1{tab}data2{tab}data3{tab}data4{end of line}
data5{tab}data6{tab}data7{tab}data8{end of line}

where {tab} is obviously the tab keystroke.

when I read in this file using the command I mentioned in the original question, this displays in the console window only Column 1, with data1, data5, only the first column. So why is this not displaying the other columns of data?

Comment: @someperson - you can edit your question. I suggest you actually add this data to the question itself, rather than as a comment.

Answer (score 3):

Pls edit your question and put the right data. Here is what I see based on your comment

```
PS C:\Scripts\Scratch> Import-Csv -Path .\test.csv -Delimiter "`t"

Col1                          Col2                          Col3                          Col4
----                          ----                          ----                          ----
Data1                         Data2                         Data3                         Data4
Data5                         Data6                         Data7                         Data8
```

Comment: thank you for the response. I've been able to figure out the problem. The command actually was importing the data, but for a reason I don't understand yet, the columns were spaced so far apart that they were way off the page (I had to scroll to the right to see the other data). So basically the data was there but because of the width I could not see it.

I was able to somewhat solve the problem by adding
    | format-table -autosize
So I guess a more accurate question now is why the import-csv command spaced the columns so far apart?

Comment: `Import-Csv` doesn't do pretty-printing. If you'd like to have an easier-to-read output, try piping to Format-Table e.g. `Import-Csv ... | ft -auto`